# How To Print to Star sp700 Thermal Printer Using PHP Windows

Tags: php, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm creating point of sales web based application using PHP. this application must can print to thermal printer. I use Star SP700. I'm already install printer driver and testing with "printer test page", and its works.

I tried using Mike42/escpos and following instruction from documentation

```
    require_once APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

    $connector = new FilePrintConnector("php://stdout");
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
    $printer -> cut();
    $printer -> close();
```

but this script giving me a blank page and not printing anything (on screen and printer). I'm using windows 10. how can fix this problem ? I expect my PHP script can print to thermal printer.

Comment: Is the setting mode different? How about changing the printer mode and device driver according to the manual or setting tool? [Software Installation Manual](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/MannualFolder/Software_im_en.pdf)

Comment: @kunif I'm still facing problem. but found alternative solution from this https://medium.com/@adenovid/cara-print-ke-printer-pos-langsung-dari-browser-d53f8e5e104e

Answer (score 0):

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
$profile = CapabilityProfile::load("SP2000")
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://computer/printer");
$printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.